# Failing to access setter method of a web-component

Tags: javascript, web-component

I building a web-component and within its constructor using template to initialize its substructure. A part of this substructure is another web-component whose setter method I wish to call. I get the sub-component by querying DOM tree that was created via the template, but through this only standard `Element` properties are accessible.

It is a bit of a complex problem and it might be I am missing something fundamental. It seems to be related with the fact that one web component uses another web component via the template clone. It was suggested [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70003531/using-functions-defined-within-web-component) that the problem might be due to sub-component not being loaded/defined. I don't understand this, especially since I can not get the proposed solution to work. I would also assume that whatever JS engine browser is running is smart enough to resolve `import` dependencies and does not run the code if its imports are not ready. Am I over simplistic with this?

A simple reproducible example that fails deterministically is indispensable. So I have managed to created a simple replica that demonstrates the problem. For the purpose of consistency I have used the same multi-file structure of the design as in the original:

- **component_a.js**

```
    class CompA extends HTMLElement
    {
        constructor()
        {
            super();
            this.attachShadow({mode: "open"});
          this.shadowRoot.append(CompA.template.content.cloneNode(true));
    
                this._value = 0;
          this.shadowRoot.getElementById('top').innerHTML = "A=" + this._value;
        }
    
        set value(x)
      {
        this._value = 2*x;
        this.shadowRoot.getElementById('top').innerHTML = "A=" + this._value;
        console.log('Value set on CompA');
      }
    }
    
    CompA.template = document.createElement("template");
    CompA.template.innerHTML = `<div id='top'></div>`;
    
    customElements.define("comp-a", CompA);
    
    export { CompA };
```

- **component_b.js**

```
    import { CompA } from "./component_a.js"
    
    class CompB extends HTMLElement
    {
        constructor()
        {
            super();
            this.attachShadow({mode: "open"});
          this.shadowRoot.append(CompB.template.content.cloneNode(true));
    
          let s = this.shadowRoot.getElementById('subcomponent');
          console.log(s.constructor.name);
          console.log(s.matches(':defined'));
          s.value = 1;
        }
    
        set value(x)
      {
        this.shadowRoot.getElementById('subcomponent').value = x;
        console.log('Value set on CompB');
      }
    }
    
    CompB.template = document.createElement("template");
    CompB.template.innerHTML = `<div>
      <span>Component B:</span>
      <comp-a id='subcomponent'></comp-a>
    </div>`;
    
    customElements.define("comp-b", CompB);
    
    export { CompB };
```

- **question.js**

```
    import { CompB } from "./component_b.js"
    
    window.onload = (event) =>
    {
      let x = document.createElement('comp-b');
      document.body.append(x);
      x.value = 10;
    }
```

- **question.html**

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang=en>
    <head>
        <meta charset=utf-8>
        <title>question</title>
      <script type='module' src='./question.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**Expected behavior:**
On question.html load `<comp-b>` is created and inserted onto the page. Its setter method is called with argument of 10. During this creation of `<comp-b>` in its constructor `<comp-a>` is appended via the template provided. Once instantiated, it is referenced by variable `s` and its setter method should be called - producing `A=20` innerHTML. So the page should be:

```
Component B:
A=20
```

with the expected console output:

```
CompB
true
Value set on CompA
Value set on CompA
Value set on CompB
```

**Observed behavior:**
Variable `s` is indeed pointing to the correct element, however `s.value = 1;` does not call the setter of `CompA` but simply assigns property with value of 1 to the element, thus living its default value in place. The page is:

```
Component B:
A=0
```

with the console output:

```
HTMLElement
false
Value set on CompB
```

**Question:**
Can someone explain me why this fails and how to force JS to associate entire specified `CompA` with the `s`, not only the `Element`?
Please feel free to suggest further possible diagnosing of the problem?

Comment: Hi! Please reduce the code to a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button); [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/).

Comment: @T.J. Hard to simulate imports here, isn't it?

Comment: @connexo - Yes, sadly, but it's irrelevant. The question isn't about import/export. A [mcve] snippet is entirely feasible in this case.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder It *kind of* is about import, because assuming `CompA` imports `CompB` that should run the call to `customElements.define('comp-b', CompB)`, so basically OP shouldn't run into any issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget the `import` and `whenDefined` mumbo jumbo.

There are 2 root causes for your problem:

1. `template` is upgraded **a-sync**
   when you append it to the shadowDOM the `constructor` code **continues**,
   and the Template HTML (now in shadowDOM) is ***upgraded*** once [the Event Loop](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ) is done.
2. `.getElementById` finds `HTMLUnknownElements`
   `HTMLUnknownElements` are `HTMLElements`, thus your `constructor.name` says `HTMLElement`, and you [can do anything you want with them](https://dev.to/dannyengelman/web-components-using-unknownhtmlelements-for-better-semantic-html-5d8c).
   They are just **not** ***upgraded*** Web Components ***yet***,
   as you found with your `matches(":defined")` code

And, yes, ***alas*** nearly every blog shows a `createElement("template")` pattern.
You don't need this mumbo jumbo either:

```
CompB.template = document.createElement("template");
CompB.template.innerHTML = `<div>
  <span>Component B:</span>
  <comp-a id='subcomponent'></comp-a>
</div>`;
```

#### Solution

Make your `constructor` do:

```
super()
  .attachShadow({mode: "open"})
  .innerHTML = `<div>
                   <span>Component B:</span>
                   <comp-a id='subcomponent'></comp-a>
                </div>`;
```

And your HTML will be parsed/upgraded **synchronous** (render blocking)

Don't want to use `innerHTML`? Build your HTML with `.createElement("div")`

`.createElement("template")` and `<template>` are upgraded A-sync.
Then understand [how to delay your code (in the `connectedCallback`)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61971919/wait-for-element-upgrade-in-connectedcallback-firefox-and-chromium-differences)

##### and in general

Do **not** do DOM (I am not saying *shadowDOM*!!) updates in the `constructor`, that work should be done in the `connectedCallback`. There are cases where there is NO DOM in the `constructor` (think SSR and `.createElement("my-component")`

---

PS. I am not a fan of this pattern:

```
export { CompA } from './comp-a/comp-a.js';
export { CompB } from './comp-b/comp-b.js';

const componentsToRegister = { 
    CompA, 
    CompB,
}

for (const clazz of Object.values(componentsToRegister)) {
   customElements.define(clazz.TAG_NAME, clazz);
}
```

You are creating dependencies.
**When** or **Where** a Web Component is defined should not matter, just like Lego bricks are Lego bricks.

"exporting" a class is highly overrated.

```
customElements.define("my-element", class extends HTMLElement{

})
```

does the job (nearly) always. Use `export` when you start to use BaseClasses for your own Elements.

You don't (always) need am exported class, you can [steal someone else Components](https://dev.to/dannyengelman/how-to-cheat-with-web-components-295o)

```
<script>
customElements.define( "poker-card", 
  class extends customElements.get("card-t") {})
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap any access to the subcomponent's API like this, assuming `s` holds a reference to your `<comp-a>` DOM node:

```js
customElements.whenDefined('comp-a').then(() => s.value = 1);
```

Another solution (which is what I am using in the web component lib I'm currently developing for a customer), is to give each and every component a static getter `TAG_NAME` like this:

```js
export class CompA extends HTMLElement {
    static get TAG_NAME() { return 'comp-a'; }
}
```

**and remove the call to `customElements.define` from the component file.**

Then, create a file called `components.js`:

```js
export { CompA } from './comp-a/comp-a.js';
export { CompB } from './comp-b/comp-b.js';

const componentsToRegister = { 
    CompA, 
    CompB,
}

for (const clazz of Object.values(componentsToRegister)) {
   customElements.define(clazz.TAG_NAME, clazz);
}
```

This allows very explicit control over which components get registered in what order, simply by ordering the properties in `componentsToRegister`.